# yacc $1 pass to variable in c?

Tags: yacc

I am working with lex and yacc, and I wonder how can I pass a value from $1 to a variable in c, in order to print it on the main?

file.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
...
%token<num> NUM
%%
expression : NUM     {   printf("number:%d;\n", $1);}
           ;
%%
int main(){
       yyparse();
printf("number is:%d;\n", var);
return 0;
}
```

doing something like '$1=var' to pass the value to the variable?

Comment: Actually `var = $1;` would pass the value *to* the variable, and there is nothing stopping you from doing that. All you have to do is define the variable. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: doing var=$1; solve the problem, was really simple, my bad. Thanks for the help.